# Mixing two streams and saving them to FLV with FMS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I'm trying to figure out how can I mix two NetStream objects into one FLV file using Flash Media Server 4. Saving one stream isn't problem but I have two concurrent streams (one is pure audio from Microphone object and second is Camera+Microphone) and I want to save them as single FLV using NetStream.publish(streamName, 'record').

It will be kind of live chat but only with one video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true, it is not possible with FMS, but can do it with FFMPEG, or a more simple way, save it to two different .flv files, and play back both of them at the same time.

Hope this helps.

R,

Tamas Gronas

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. You would have to encode it into single NetStream on the client side, try merging audio together (but I don't know how).

Flash Media Server 4 cannot encode anything. [[1]](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/848473?tstart=0)

http://forums.adobe.com/community/flash/flash_media_server